# Scores for DecisionTreeRegressor parameter tuning throws errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am tuning a model with the DecisionTreeRegressor.

```
tuned_parameters = [{'splitter': ['best'],   'max_leaf_nodes': [2, 3,4,5]},
                    {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [2, 3,4,5]}]


#for Regression
scores = ['mse']
```

When I run the code, it throws an error:

**ValueError: 'mse_macro' is not a valid scoring value. Use sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()) to get valid options.**

Why is the mse not a valid macro for this regression problem? What else can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html):

> All scorer objects follow the convention that **higher return values
>   are better than lower return values**. Thus metrics which measure the
>   distance between the model and the data, like
>   `metrics.mean_squared_error`, are available as
>   `neg_mean_squared_error` which return the negated value of the metric.

All supported metrics are listed in the documentation. You can also use `print(metrics.SCORERS.keys())` to get them.

So you need `neg_mean_squared_error` instead of `mse`.